# Merging data Angular2 after click REST service

Tags: angular, service

I have a question about the following 'problem'. For a new study progress app for students we want to do the following: On startup you have all the 'courses' (CUxxx) collapsed. You only see the endresults (eindresultaten in the json later in this post)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPT27.jpg
when a user clicks on 'menu-hamburger' icon it shows the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgiZQ.jpg
You then see the 'Toetsresultaten' (testresults) from 'Eindresultaten' endresults

I have build this service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Studievoortgang, Toetsresultaten, Eindresultaten, Fasen } from '../../classes/Studievoortgang';


@Injectable()
export class StudievoortgangService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }


    public getStudieplannen(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http.get('https://apps.ips.hz.nl/angularstudievoortgang/services/studieplannen/studieplannen.json')
            .map((res: any) => res.json()).catch(() => Observable.of([]));
    }

    public getStudent(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('https://apps.ips.hz.nl/angularstudievoortgang/services/student/student.json')
            .map((res: any) => res.json()).catch(() => Observable.of({}));
    }

    public getStudievoortgangStudent(): Observable<any> {
        return this.getStudent().map((res: any) => res).catch(() => Observable.of([]))
            .flatMap((student: any) => {
             return this.getFasenVanStudieplannen()
                                .map((data: any) => {
                                    let Studievoortgang: any = data;
                                    student.Studievoortgang = Studievoortgang;
                                    return student;
                                });

            });
    }


    public getFasenVanStudieplannen(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.getStudieplannen().map((res: any) => res)//.catch(() => Observable.of([]))
            .flatMap((studieplannen: any[]) => {
                if (studieplannen.length > 0) {
                    return Observable.forkJoin(
                        studieplannen.map((studieplan: any) => {
                            return this.getFaseVanStudieplan(studieplan.StudieplanID)
                                .map((data: any) => {
                                    let Fasen: any = data;
                                    studieplan.Fasen = Fasen;
                                    return studieplan;
                                });
                        })
                    );
                }
                return Observable.of([]);
            });
    }

    public getFaseVanStudieplan(StudieplanID: string): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http.get('https://apps.ips.hz.nl/angularstudievoortgang/services/fasen/studieplan' + StudieplanID +'/fasen'+ '.json')
            .map((res: any) => res.json()).catch(() => Observable.of([]))
            .flatMap((fasen: any[]) => {
                if (fasen.length > 0) {
                    return Observable.forkJoin(
                        fasen.map((fase: any) => {
                            return this.getToetsresultatenVanEindresultaten(fase.NaamFase, fase.StudieplanID)
                                .map((data: any) => {
                                    let Eindresultaten: any = data;
                                    fase.Eindresultaten = Eindresultaten;
                                    return fase;
                                });
                        })
                    );
                }
                return Observable.of([]);
            });
    }

    public getToetsresultatenVanEindresultaten(fase: string, StudieplanID: string): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http.get('https://apps.ips.hz.nl/angularstudievoortgang/services/eindresultaten/studieplan' + StudieplanID + '/eindresultaten' + fase + '.json')
            .map((res: any) => res.json()).catch(() => Observable.of([]))
            .flatMap((eindresultaten: any[]) => {
                if (eindresultaten.length > 0) {
                    return Observable.forkJoin(
                        eindresultaten.map((eindresultaat: any) => {
                            return this.getToetsresultatenVanToetsmatrijs(eindresultaat.Toetsmatrijs)
                                    .map((res: any) => {
                                    let Toetsresultaten: any = res;
                                    eindresultaat.Toetsresultaten = Toetsresultaten;
                                    return eindresultaat;
                                })
                                .catch(() => Observable.of([]))
                        })

                    );

                }
                return Observable.of([]);
            });
    }

    public getToetsresultatenVanToetsmatrijs(toetsmatrijs: string): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http.get('https://apps.ips.hz.nl/angularstudievoortgang/services/toetsresultaten/' + toetsmatrijs + '.json')
            .map((res: any) => res.json())
            .catch(() => Observable.of([]))
    }
}
```

This results in the following JSON:

```
{
"Studentnummer": "00012345",
"StudentNaam": "Test name student",
"Studievoortgang": [{
    "StudieplanID": "1",
    "StudieplanNaam": "Studieplan Test",
    "CROHOCode": "12345",
    "CROHONaam": "HBO-ICT",
    "HZOpleidingID": "2100029",
    "HZOpleidingNaam": "HBO-ICT",
    "Fasen": [{
        "StudieplanID": "1",
        "NaamFase": "Propedeuse",
        "AantalTeBehalenEC": "60",
        "AantalVirtueelTotaalEC": "10",
        "AantalVastTeStellenEC": "0",
        "AantalWerkelijkTotaalEC": "25",
        "Eindresultaten": [{
            "Cursus": "CU01010",
            "TijdsperiodeID": "25",
            "Eindresultaat": "8",
            "Toetsmatrijs": "1",
            "CursusEC": "15",
            "EindresultaatVirtueelEC": "0",
            "EindresultaatVastTeStellenEC": "0",
            "EindresultaatVastgesteldeEC": "15",
            "OpmerkingEindresultaat": "Geen",
            "KleurEindresultaat": "Red",
            "Toetsresultaten": [{
                "NaamToets": "Test1",
                "Volgnummer": "1",
                "Resultaat": "7",
                "Weging": "50%",
                "ECWaarde": "1,25",
                "VirtueelECWaarde": "0",
                "ECVastTeStellen": "0",
                "ECVastgesteld": "1,25",
                "OpmerkingToetsresultaat": "Geen",
                "KleurToetsresultaat": "Red"
            }, {
                "NaamToets": "Test2",
                "Volgnummer": "2",
                "Resultaat": "5",
                "Weging": "50%",
                "ECWaarde": "1,25",
                "VirtueelECWaarde": "0",
                "ECVastTeStellen": "0",
                "ECVastgesteld": "1,25",
                "OpmerkingToetsresultaat": "Geen",
                "KleurToetsresultaat": "Red"
            }]
        }, {
            "Cursus": "CU025060",
            "TijdsperiodeID": "25",
            "Eindresultaat": "7",
            "Toetsmatrijs": "2",
            "CursusEC": "15",
            "EindresultaatVirtueelEC": "0",
            "EindresultaatVastTeStellenEC": "0",
            "EindresultaatVastgesteldeEC": "15",
            "OpmerkingEindresultaat": "Geen",
            "KleurEindresultaat": "Red",
            "Toetsresultaten": [{
                "NaamToets": "Plan van aanpak",
                "Volgnummer": "1",
                "Resultaat": "7",
                "Weging": "50%",
                "ECWaarde": "1,25",
                "VirtueelECWaarde": "0",
                "ECVastTeStellen": "0",
                "ECVastgesteld": "1,25",
                "OpmerkingToetsresultaat": "Geen",
                "KleurToetsresultaat": "Red"
            }, {
                "NaamToets": "Onderzoek",
                "Volgnummer": "2",
                "Resultaat": "5",
                "Weging": "50%",
                "ECWaarde": "1,25",
                "VirtueelECWaarde": "0",
                "ECVastTeStellen": "0",
                "ECVastgesteld": "1,25",
                "OpmerkingToetsresultaat": "Geen",
                "KleurToetsresultaat": "Red"
            }]
        }, {
            "StudieplanID": "1",
            "NaamFase": "Hoofdfase",
            "AantalTeBehalenEC": "180",
            "AantalVirtueelTotaalEC": "10",
            "AantalVastTeStellenEC": "0",
            "AantalWerkelijkTotaalEC": "25",
            "Eindresultaten": [{
                "Cursus": "CU01234",
                "TijdsperiodeID": "26",
                "Eindresultaat": "5.7",
                "Toetsmatrijs": "10",
                "CursusEC": "15",
                "EindresultaatVirtueelEC": "0",
                "EindresultaatVastTeStellenEC": "0",
                "EindresultaatVastgesteldeEC": "15",
                "OpmerkingEindresultaat": "Geen",
                "KleurEindresultaat": "Red",
                "Toetsresultaten": [{
                    "NaamToets": "Toetsje",
                    "Volgnummer": "1",
                    "Resultaat": "7",
                    "Weging": "50%",
                    "ECWaarde": "1,25",
                    "VirtueelECWaarde": "0",
                    "ECVastTeStellen": "0",
                    "ECVastgesteld": "1,25",
                    "OpmerkingToetsresultaat": "Geen",
                    "KleurToetsresultaat": "Red"
                }, {
                    "NaamToets": "Rapport",
                    "Volgnummer": "2",
                    "Resultaat": "5",
                    "Weging": "50%",
                    "ECWaarde": "1,25",
                    "VirtueelECWaarde": "0",
                    "ECVastTeStellen": "0",
                    "ECVastgesteld": "1,25",
                    "OpmerkingToetsresultaat": "Geen",
                    "KleurToetsresultaat": "Red"
                }]

            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

}

With the above service we get all the 'Toetsresultaten' for every 'Eindresultaat'. What we actually want is to only get the 'Toetsresultaten' where a user clicked on the corresponding 'menu-hamburger'. So i need some way to do this, but i don't know how. ( i am new to Angular). Do you guys have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Component:

studievoortgang.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import { StudievoortgangService } from '../../core/services/studievoortgang.service';
import { Studievoortgang } from '../../classes/Studievoortgang';

@Component({
    selector: 'studievoortgang-component',
    templateUrl: 'studievoortgang.component.html'

})

export class StudievoortgangComponent implements OnInit {
    public show = {};
    public ExpCursus: string;
    public studievoortgang: Studievoortgang[];
    public test: Studievoortgang[];
    public studievoortgangStudent: any[];
    public resultaat: string;

    constructor(
        private studievoortgangService: StudievoortgangService

    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
          this.getStudievoortgangStudent();
    }

   getStudievoortgangStudent() {
        this.studievoortgangService.getStudievoortgangStudent().subscribe(studievoortgangStudent => this.studievoortgangStudent = studievoortgangStudent, error => console.log(error),
            () => console.log('Haal alle studievoortgang data op inclusief toetsresultaten')
        );
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: The json result is from calling which method in your service?

Comment: Also share your components or at least describe how your components look like... I am particularly interested in knowing whether "testresult" is implemented as a different component from "menu-humburger"...

Comment: I edited the start post. OnInit i start this.getStudievoortgangStudent(); which will fire 'getStudievoortgangStudent()' from the 'studievoortgangservice'

Comment: I found a solution and that is to use a detail component to show the testresults with an Input().

Comment: That sounds about right. Good job!